# Away3d Camera Path

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

How to know the coordinates of the path if you know the azimuthal angle. I wanna move my camera around an object in away 3d.

Answer (score 1):

Move camera in [Spherical coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) by [Interpolating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) from  starting  azimuthal angle to target - it will be your trajectory.
You can [convert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Coordinate_system_conversions) from\to Cartesian coordinate system to retrive\pass current coordinate to away3d renderer.

You all so may want to use non-linear camera acceleration(for more realistic feel) it can be implemented with [Bézier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

PS. I will be thankful if your publish you realisation because i will need this functional in my next project. You will save me a lot of time :)

Or just use translation and rotation methods that camera inherits from [Object3D](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/core/base/Object3D.html)  it's all covered in Away3D example projects. Allso [Away3D has path helper package](https://github.com/away3d/away3d-core-fp11/tree/master/src/away3d/paths)